# What to do when main() function isn’t calling/executing the other functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a main() function and also 3 others and I am trying to get the other 3 to be executed into main()

I had it working then I messed it up at the very end, so I commented it out since it is not calling the 3 other functions.

```
# The program displays the letter grade and associated message for each exam score
#   and the average exam score
# The program will not contain any repeated code and have a minimum of two functions besides Main.

def main():
  # ask user to enter test scores
    score = int(input("Enter your test scores separate by spaces, no commas: "))

# display test score
def showLetters(num, letterGrade):
    print(f"{num:.1f} is  an {letterGrade}\n")

# display score message
def examScores(num):
    if 90 <= num <= 100:
        letterGrade = "A"
        print("Excellent Work")
    elif 80 <= num <= 89:
        letterGrade = "B"
        print("Nice job")
    elif 70 <= num <= 79:
        letterGrade = "C"
        print("Not bad")
    elif 60 <= num <= 69:
        letterGrade = "D"
        print("Room for improvement")
    else:
        letterGrade = "F"
        print("Go back and review")
    return letterGrade


# calculate average of all scores entered by user
def calcAverages(grades):
    numbers = scores.split()
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])
    print("Average exam score: ", sum(numbers) / len(numbers))

    # ask user to repeat or quit
    answer = str(input('Please enter "y" to run program again or "n" to exit: '))
    if answer.lower() == 'n':
        print('Thank you for using! Goodbye!')
        sys.exit()
    elif answer.lower() == 'y':
        main()



# ??? = main()
# for n in ????? :
#    showLetters(n, examScores(n, calcAverages(????)))
```

Comment: you need to store the user data. once you store the user data when user asked for exit, from that store data you can calculate the result

Comment: Do you mean like a text file? I dont think we have gotten that far into the course for me to be able to use that method.

Comment: you can use dictionary object to save the details . eg  `{1: {"firstname":"xyz", "lastname":"abc", "class1":'a'}, 2 :{"firstname":"aaA", "lastname":eqeq"..}}` like this

Answer (score 2):

I made minor edits to your program and you now have the average values.

I have highlighted only the lines that need addition.

```
counter = 0  # tracks the number of times the function is called

#added the below 2 lines after counter
sumCredit = 0 #tracks the sum credit for all the students
sumStudyHrs = 0 #track the sum of the study hours for all the students

def myfunction():
    global counter  # tracks the number of times the function is called

    #added two more global variables to keep track of the averages

    global sumCredit #track the sum credit
    global sumStudyHrs #track the sum study hours
```

the rest of the code can stay as is. Immediately after you print the student details, you need to accumulate the values so you can calculate the average.

```
    print("Study hours: " + str(sumHours))

    #added the below 2 lines after your print statements
    sumCredit += classes
    sumStudyHrs += sumHours

    # Ask user if they want to end or restart
```

Now you need to use this information for your calculation.

When you print the average, use the above variables to compute the average.

```
        print("Total Students: " + str(counter))  # tracks the number of times the function is called

        #modified your average credits and average study with correct numerator

        print("Average Credits: " + str(sumCredit / counter)) #computer average credits
        print("Average Study Hours: " + str(sumStudyHrs / counter)) #compute average study hours

        print('Thank you for using! Goodbye!')
```

This should give you the desired results.

Let me know if you need the full code.

Comment: you saved my life! thank you thank you thank yoooou ---- the only thing i changed to make the math work was ```sumCredit += creditSum```